# Efficiency: Selecting object not in DOM with jQuery

Tags: jquery, performance, optimization

I'm sure this is an oft asked question; I just can't seem to word it in a way to to find said answer.

Common practice says to minimize the number of CSS and JS files you load. However, I always made the assumption that if I had a jQuery selector searching that didn't find anything (specially a class selector), it was much slower to do that then to load a separate page.

For example, I wrote a private messaging system on one website. I use AJAX to send and delete messages. The selectors used for this are unused anywhere else. Am I better off:

a) Having scripts specific to a page in a separate JS file, loaded on each said page.

b) Have the code in a single page, leaving each selector to run as is

c) Have the code in a single page, but use if statements to check if we're on the particular page, and only have those selects under the if block (each page has a unique ID, so I can test for this ID and do an if/else chain)

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you're comparing. Are you comparing the speed of searching for an element in the DOM using a selector, versus the speed of loading a page over HTTP (using AJAX)? I can't really see when these two operations would be interchangeable. Can you describe your a, b, c options in more detail?

Comment: Sorry, not a comparison. I'm interested in learning about best practices. If I load one JS file and it has a bunch of selectors that don't map to anything, will that slow it down enough to warrant me separating those code chunks into a separate JS file, or into separate if/then blocks? Or does is it not slow enough in comparison to page loads to warrant splitting it up.